# Powershell : ForEach Loop

Tags: powershell

How to edits the questions is like to be ask by someone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Export-Csv` for this.

First, you'll want to create objects rather than strings from the two arrays:

```
$objects = foreach($f1 in $file1)
{
    foreach($f2 in $file2)
    {
        New-Object psobject -Property @{
            Server = $f1
            HotfixID = $f2
        }
    }
}
```

Now we can pipe these to `Export-Csv` and specify a delimiter (a space in your case):

```
$objects |Export-Csv -Path "C:\path\to\output.file" -Delimiter ' ' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

You've fallen into the same trap as many others when working with PowerShell - you're manipulating text instead of objects.

Instead of concatenating strings (`{$f1+","+$f2}`), create an object:

```
{ New-Object PSObject -Property @{ "Server" = $f1; "Hotfix" = $f2 } }
```

Then, wrap the whole `ForEach` in parentheses, and assign to a variable:

```
$hfdata = ( ForEach ... )
```

...and finally, `Export-CSV` the array:

```
Export-CSV -InputObject $hfdata -Path $savefile
```